# Java DataFlavor for java.util.Map

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, awt

What is the correct way to construct a DataFlavor for a java.util.Map

For an array i do that:

```
DataFlavor[]{new DataFlavor(
                     DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + 
                     ";class=\"" + Foo[].class.getName() + "\"")}
```

But not sure what will be the equivalent for a Map.

clarification:

I want to transfer a `Map<Foo, Bar>` but i cannot do `Map<Foo, Bar>.class`.